# Firebase Firestore Emulator not updating document queries

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, emulation

When using the firestore emulator and the JavaScript client I am unable to see updates.  The scenario is:

1. I have an existing collection of documents and I make a query to fetch the collection. All is working as expected.
2. I update the collection (add, delete or update a document in the collection). Either through code or manually through the emulator web ui.
3. I query the collection.  I never see the updates, no matter what i do I only see the results of the first query.  The only way i can see the updates is restarting the emulator.

This works just fine when not using the emulator.

Thinking the emulator was forcing a read from cache, I tried to force it to fetch from the server using the getDocsFromServer method, but that didn't work.

I searched for a know issue with the emulators but haven't found a reference to this issue.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's likely you're writing to the wrong database. Please include the command you use to start the emulators and the code that is querying the collection (including the connectToEmulator call(s)). Also check `firebase use` if you're not specifying a project in the emulators:start command.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen when you switch firebase project in your `firebase-tools` and forget to switch it back.

Check the output from:

```bash
firebase projects:list
```

and compare to your `PROJECT_ID` on the client in the init script:

```
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "AIza....",                             
  appId: "1:27992087142:web:ce....",              
  projectId: "PROJECT_ID",               
  authDomain: "YOUR_APP.firebaseapp.com",         
  databaseURL: "https://YOUR_APP.firebaseio.com", 
  storageBucket: "YOUR_APP.appspot.com",          
  messagingSenderId: "123456789",                 
  measurementId: "G-12345"                        
});
```